# What parameters should take a controller's method, which is deleting records from the database?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm creating a simple training project. I've implemented a controller method, which deletes an item from the list. The method is looking like this:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/topic")
public class TopicController {

    @Autowired
    private TopicService service;

    ...

    @RequestMapping(value = "/deleteComment/{commentId}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String deleteComment(@PathVariable int commentId, BindingResult result, Model model){

        Comment deletedComment = commentService.findCommentByID(commentId);
        if (deletedComment != null) {
            commentService.deleteComment(deletedComment);
        }

        return "refresh:";
   }

}
```

This method is called from the button-tag, which is looking in the following way:

```
<form><button formaction = "../deleteComment/1" formmethod = "post">delete</button></form>
```

In my project the form-tag is looking like a clickable button. But there is a serious problem: controller's method is never triggered. How can I trigger it, using a button-tag?

P.S. the call is performed from the page with URI **http://localhost:8080/simpleblog/topic/details/2** and controller's URI is the **http://localhost:8080/simpleblog/topic/deleteComment/2**

**UPDATE:**

I've created hyperlink 'delete', clicking on which should delete a comment, and I received an exception

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Errors/BindingResult argument declared without preceding model attribute. Check your handler method signature!
```

And it's true: I really have no **@ModelAttribute** in my controller method, preceding **BindingResult** parameter. But I have no clue, which type of type should it be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<form>`'s `method` attribute is `GET` by default. I don't know what are you trying to do with `formmethod` and `formaction` attributes, but in default [HTML](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp) they mean nothing.

You must try something like:

```
<form action="../deleteComment/1" method="post">
    <button>delete</button>
</form>
```

**EDIT:**

You are declaring some unused parameters in your method. BindingResult must be used with a `@Valid` annotated attribute (search `@Valid` [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html) to see some examples), but this is not your case. So, please just try:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/deleteComment/{commentId}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String deleteComment(@PathVariable int commentId){
    ...
}
```

Comment: I've used <button> tag's properties. They are prior to <form> tag's properties, and overrides them

Comment: Sorry, but "Input" tag with type "submit" passed a control flow to the right method